# Bind fails with short domain name

Tags: server, dns, bind

I'm having troubles getting Bind to work with a two character long domain name. Is this a known issue? I haven't found anything related to this anywhere.

I have about 50 domains up and running in my Bind config, and they all run just fine. However when I try to add a domain name consisting of only two characters Bind won't start.

When this is added to my named.conf

```
zone "ll.ll" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/master/db.ll.ll";
};
```

Bind throws me "[FAIL] Starting domain name service...: bind9 failed!" when I try to restart the service.

While the following works just fine:

```
zone "lll.ll" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/master/db.ll.ll";
};
```

No complains from Bind with this zone. All of my other domains runs just fine and the setup in the zone files are identical to the db.ll.ll - the only thing that differs is the length of the domain name.

Comment: Can any insight be gained from `/var/log/syslog`? perhaps via `grep named /var/log/syslog`